# Firefox CSS triangle render error

Tags: css, firefox, styling, antialiasing, direct2d

I have written some CSS which is able to create a 'wonky' div which is IE8 compatible by using CSS triangles and pseudo-elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/9WaPa/2/

This method is working perfectly in IE8+ and all versions of Chrome. Firefox however is proving an issue.

On my machine the edges are rending perfectly, but when testing on other systems running a variety of OSs and Firefox versions, and the edges of the triangles become jagged (not antialiased) seemingly at random.

After some investigation I found this style:

```
-moz-transform: scale(0.9999);
```

Which will fix the jagged edge, the problem is when that style is applied and the edge was not jagged for that user, then some very random graphical bugs start playing up (flickering and colour bleeding).

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SFILWHK.png]

After much research and comparing the separate machines I think the issue is to do with which machines have 'Direct2D' enabled on them. From my tests every machine that did not have Direct2D running was showing the jagged edge.

So my question is: Does anyone know of a style that will fix the jagged edge, without causing crazy graphical bugs in Direct2D? Or possibly; does anyone know a way for a site to detect the presence of Direct2D on a machine so a style could be added in by JS?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't test on Direct2D but this 3d transform works for me: `-moz-transform: rotateY(0.1deg);` (http://jsfiddle.net/9WaPa/5/)

Comment: @Moob That style does fix the problem, same as my scale did, and on my machine it is not causing any Direct2D issues that I can see, which is excellent. I'll run back through all of the test machines but it is looking promising. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Moob Unfortunately it seems the Direct2D machines are still giving out a graphical bug when the page is scrolled so the element moves out of and back into the visible area. http://i.imgur.com/3LxcO2j.png  It is still an improvement over the scale version though, much less noticeable on page load.

Comment: Interesting. I can't test this suggestion but you could try applying the rotateY transform to the element's parent or even the `body`. Just a thought - absolutely no idea if it will help but the element is antialiased with the transform just on the `body` or `.one` (http://jsfiddle.net/9WaPa/8/)

Comment: The problem persists sadly, doesn't seem to matter what element gets the rotateY it still goes glitchy when it scrolls off screen and back again. Worth a try though.

Comment: So it seems the issue is with Direct2D itself and may only be apparent for certain graphics cards (presumably older ones). Unless you get lucky and hit upon a combination of transforms that work without glitches I see no real solution. Sorry.

Comment: @Moob Yea that was the conclusion I had settled down on when I posted the question, I was just holding out hope for a transform that wouldn't break Direct2D. Thanks for all your help anyway mate.